Should batch normalization be used before or after, when using sigmoid or tanh?
This prior post discusses Batch-norm with Relu ordering.
I have a similar question but pertaining to sigmoid or tanh kind of activation functions. Should batch-norm be used before or after? Is there a difference?

We add the BN transform immediately before the nonlinearity, by normalizing x = Wu+ b. We could have also normalized the layer inputs u, but since u is likely the output of another nonlinearity, the shape of its distribution is likely to change during training, and constraining its first and second moments would not eliminate the covariate shift. In contrast, Wu + b is more likely to have a symmetric, non-sparse distribution, that is “more Gaussian” (Hyvarinen & Oja, 2000); normalizing it is likely to produce activations with a stable distribution.

^ Quote from the original BN paper. In the BN paper they seem to have the batch-norm before the sigmoid and evaluate it on MNIST dataset and show improved results.

It may be more appropriate after the activation function if for s-shaped functions like the hyperbolic tangent and logistic function.

^ However, this BN article claims that putting BN after sigmoid might be better. Doesn't give any justification...
Does anyone know the difference/have mathematical justification? If you put ordering as (Linear->BN->Sig) then the bias term in the linear layer and the BN can cancel out and makes training faster. But (BN->sig) would mean that the discrimination from sigmoid is less contrastive. This means that you would not have as much confidence in the 'on/off'-ness of the activation?
In my current use case, I see that BN after (LL->Sig->BN) is improving my results. I do not understand any why.
I wrote this code to visualize some differences. I understand why the output looks as it does, but I do not understand how it carries over to the learning process.


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Generate a random uniform distribution D
np.random.seed(0)
D = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 1000)

# Function to apply sigmoid and layer normalization
def sigmoid_then_layernorm(data):
    sigmoid_data = torch.sigmoid(torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32))
    layernorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(sigmoid_data.shape)
    normalized_data = layernorm(sigmoid_data)
    return normalized_data.detach().numpy()

# Function to apply layer normalization and then sigmoid
def layernorm_then_sigmoid(data):
    data_tensor = torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32)
    layernorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(data_tensor.shape)
    normalized_data = layernorm(data_tensor)
    sigmoid_data = torch.sigmoid(normalized_data)
    return sigmoid_data.detach().numpy()

# Apply both methods
sigmoid_then_layernorm_data = sigmoid_then_layernorm(D)
layernorm_then_sigmoid_data = layernorm_then_sigmoid(D)

# Plot the distributions
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.hist(sigmoid_then_layernorm_data, bins=50, alpha=0.7, label='Sigmoid then LayerNorm')
plt.title('Sigmoid then LayerNorm')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(layernorm_then_sigmoid_data, bins=50, alpha=0.7, label='LayerNorm then Sigmoid')
plt.title('LayerNorm then Sigmoid')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Generate a normal distribution D
D = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

# Apply both methods
sigmoid_then_layernorm_data = sigmoid_then_layernorm(D)
layernorm_then_sigmoid_data = layernorm_then_sigmoid(D)

# Plot the distributions
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.hist(sigmoid_then_layernorm_data, bins=50, alpha=0.7, label='Sigmoid then LayerNorm')
plt.title('Sigmoid then LayerNorm')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(layernorm_then_sigmoid_data, bins=50, alpha=0.7, label='LayerNorm then Sigmoid')
plt.title('LayerNorm then Sigmoid')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

